# How to hide the basic authorization credential in browser response header?

Tags: api, authentication, https, basic-authentication, api-auth

I've implemented Basic Authorization for API Authentication purposes. But, when I send my credential in API access those credentials show like the below picture in the Authorization header.

So, How to hide my credential in this header?

Thank you in advance.

[image: Browser Network Header]

Comment: If the server requires to use HTTP Basic auth then having username:password base64 encoded in every request is required. That is the way HTTP basic aus is defined in RFC7617.

Comment: Is there any way of hiding those credentials inside the **Network console**

Comment: No. And this also doesn't make sense. If you just have entered the credentials there is no problem in showing them in the browser developer tools.

Comment: Then what's the point of using basic auth?

Comment: The point of Basic auth is transferring username and password in every request to the server so the server can check if you are authorized to do the request.

Comment: And that's why it's called BASIC Auth. It's extremely BASIC authentication.

Comment: Yes, got it. Thank you