# SAP UI5 / Cannot get data from Service through destination

Tags: sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

I am developing a ui5 app using the managed app router to try to consume destinations from the BTP. The destination uses a BasicAuthentication with a technical username and password and the connection works but when I am trying to access the data from my UI5 app I get a 401 Unauthorized response code.

In the xs-app.json of my app is the authenticationType xsuaa. I can provide some file and snippets if this helps.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need to have your SAPUI5 app send the HTTP Authentication header in the request. You can use Chrome DevTools to see that HTTP header; it should have the name 'Authorization' followed by a 'Basic' + basic64 cipher.
(exemple here [How to hide the basic authorization credential in browser response header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68250902/how-to-hide-the-basic-authorization-credential-in-browser-response-header) )

About Basic Auth : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication

Instead of setting directly that HTTTP header (with username/password) in your app, I'd recommend to use your server authentication default process.